# Redmine and OTRS integration

Tags: project-management, redmine, gitlab, application-lifecycle, otrs

Ticket Management: OTRS. (I can't change this tool but need to integrate everything to OTRS)

Project Management Tool: Actually I was looking for a good project management tool which can also  contains Kanban. Redmine has a plugin for Kanban. 
Repository: As repository server I decided to use git with gitLab interface.

Now I'm wondering that is there way to integrate Redmine with OTRS or if my choices are not good for Application Life Cycle, what would you offer which is open source?

Answer (score 3):

In our company we have integrated OTRS and Redmine via emails. Of course such integration cannot be called complete, but we have solved our task: OTRS users and Redmine users can talk each over via their own systems. Someone in Redmine can create an issue and the issue may be forwarded to OTRS.

Some details.

OTRS has ticket ID in e-mail subject like this: [Ticket#2015032394000015] and Redmine - like this: [#123] (i.e. completely different). Small patch for Redmine resolves where is alien ticket ID (OTRS's) and where is own (Redmine's). 
Both systems can send and receive e-mails.

Also we use [Redmine helpdesk plugin](https://github.com/jfqd/redmine_helpdesk) to not spamming OTRS by developer's discussions, status updates etc. For tickets from OTRS "owner-email" field filled by OTRS's emission e-mail address. Subject of the tickets in Redmine should contain OTRS's ticket number. So should be done in OTRS. So the proposed workflow if the tickets initially created in the OTRS will be:

1. User -> OTRS: problem description
2. OTRS -> User: auto-response
3. (... conversation between the user and the support...)
4. OTRS -> Redmine: claim to developers
5. Redmine -> OTRS: auto-response with Redmine ticket number. OTRS should update ticket subject using Redmine's ticket ID.
6. (... conversation between the support and the developer...)

etc.

The crucial thing is to update OTRS ticket's subject in 5-th point.

Answer (score 2):

There are no answers :( it is very interesting question...

Result of my small investigation:
I will put here several links which may be will purtly useful for you:
http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/24573 (contain two useful links on two plugins, but i do not have time for testing these plugins)

http://forums.otterhub.org/viewtopic.php?t=21501